# Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SYNC_ri_res_to_WC_PersonAddress, Line 24 [Batch Start Line 0] Conversion failed when converting the

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I run the following query:

```
update ri_res
set name_last = 'onion',
    name_first = 'Forest',
    addr1 = '2872 Loki Laufeyson',
    city = 'Queens',
    [state] = 'NY',
    zip = '11374',
    county = 'West',
    phone = '4152366293',
    ssn = '912308719',
    sex = 'M',
    birthplace = 'Madison',
    birth_date = '3/1/1947',
    uniqueid = newid()
where cono = 'JC' and resno = '216'
```

I am getting the following error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SYNC_ri_res_to_WC_PersonAddress,
>   Line 24 [Batch Start Line 0] Conversion failed when converting the
>   varchar value '1094_2' to data type int.

Listed below is the stored procedure:

```
USE [WestCounty]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [Base360].[SYNC_ri_res_to_WC_PersonAddress]    Script Date: 2/25/2019 9:12:39 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [Base360].[SYNC_ri_res_to_WC_PersonAddress]
    @ConoResnos XML
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  DECLARE @Payload as XML = @ConoResnos;
/* Address (ri_res address fields) */
INSERT INTO Base360.Address_Base (Address1, Address2, City, AddressStateID, Zipcode, AddressCountyID, EnterpriseID)
 select distinct i.addr1, i.addr2, i.city, S.AddressStateID, i.zip, county.AddressCountyID,(select top 1 EnterpriseID from Base360.Facility_Base where FacilityID > 0)
    FROM ri_res i with(nolock)
    INNER JOIN (SELECT x.value('cono[1]','varchar(4)') as cono, x.value('resno[1]','INT') as resno  FROM @Payload.nodes('/Inserted/Row') AS T(x)) as cr 
    on cr.cono = i.cono and cr.resno = i.resno
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Base360].[AddressState] S ON i.state = S.StateCode
LEFT OUTER JOIN Base360.AddressCounty county on i.county = county.CountyName and S.AddressStateID = county.AddressStateID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [Base360].[Address_Base] A with(nolock)
                    ON ISNULL(addr1,'')  = ISNULL(A.Address1 ,'')
                    AND isnull(addr2,'') = isnull(A.Address2,'') 
                    AND isnull(S.AddressStateID,'') = ISNULL(A.AddressStateID,'')
                    AND isnull(i.city,'') = isnull(A.City,'')
                    AND isnull(SUBSTRING(i.[zip], 1, 5),'') = isnull(SUBSTRING(A.ZipCode,1,5),'')
                    AND isnull(county.AddressCountyID,'') = ISNULL(A.AddressCountyID,'')
        WHERE A.AddressID IS NULL and (i.addr1 is not null or i.addr2 is not null OR i.city is not null or i.state is not null or i.zip is not null or i.county is not null)
UPDATE PA SET EndDAte = GetUTCDate()
FROM ri_res rc  with(nolock)
    INNER JOIN (SELECT x.value('cono[1]','varchar(4)') as cono, x.value('resno[1]','INT') as resno  FROM @Payload.nodes('/Inserted/Row') AS T(x)) as cr 
    on cr.cono = rc.cono and cr.resno = rc.resno
INNER JOIN Base360.PersonIdentification PID with(nolock) on rc.cono = SUBSTRING(PID.PersonIdentificationValue, 0,(charindex('_',PID.PersonIdentificationValue)))
                                    AND rc.resno =  CAST(SUBSTRING(PID.PersonIdentificationValue, (charindex('_',PID.PersonIdentificationValue))+1,10) as int)
                                    AND PID.PersonIdentificationTypeID = -1
INNER JOIN Base360.PersonAddress PA on PID.PersonID = PA.PersonID and PA.AddressTypeID = -2 and PA.EndDate IS NULL

;with addyCTEInsert2 as (
        select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by isnull(A.Address1,''), isnull(A.Address2,''), isnull(A.City,''), ISNULL(A.AddressStateID,''), isnull(SUBSTRING(A.ZipCode,1,5),''), isnull(county.CountyName,'') ORDER BY CreateUTCDate) as RowNum, 
        A.AddressID, A.Address1, A.Address2, A.City, A.AddressStateID, A.Zipcode, county.AddressCountyID
        FROM ri_res i with(nolock)
        INNER JOIN (SELECT x.value('cono[1]','varchar(4)') as cono, x.value('resno[1]','INT') as resno  FROM @Payload.nodes('/Inserted/Row') AS T(x)) as cr 
        on cr.cono = i.cono and cr.resno = i.resno
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [Base360].[AddressState] S ON i.state = S.StateCode
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Base360.AddressCounty county on i.county = county.CountyName and S.AddressStateID = county.AddressStateID
                INNER JOIN [Base360].[Address_Base] A with(nolock)
                       ON ISNULL(addr1,'')  = ISNULL(A.Address1 ,'')
                    AND isnull(addr2,'') = isnull(A.Address2,'') 
                    AND isnull(S.AddressStateID,'') = ISNULL(A.AddressStateID,'')
                    AND isnull(i.city,'') = isnull(A.City,'')
                    AND isnull(SUBSTRING(i.[zip], 1, 5),'') = isnull(SUBSTRING(A.ZipCode,1,5),'')
                    AND isnull(county.AddressCountyID,'') = ISNULL(A.AddressCountyID,'')
        WHERE (i.addr1 is not null or i.addr2 is not null OR i.city is not null or i.state is not null or i.zip is not null or i.county is not null)

  )
INSERT INTO Base360.PersonAddress ([PersonID], [AddressID], [AddressTypeID], [BeginDate], [EnterpriseID])
select distinct PB.PersonID, AB.AddressID, -2 AS AddressTypeID, GetUTCDate() AS BeginDate, PB.EnterpriseID
FROM ri_res rc  with(nolock)
INNER JOIN Base360.PersonIdentification PID with(nolock) on rc.cono = SUBSTRING(PID.PersonIdentificationValue, 0,(charindex('_',PID.PersonIdentificationValue)))
                                    AND rc.resno =  CAST(SUBSTRING(PID.PersonIdentificationValue, (charindex('_',PID.PersonIdentificationValue))+1,10) as int)
                                    AND PID.PersonIdentificationTypeID = -1
INNER JOIN [Base360].[Person_Base] PB with(nolock) ON PID.PersonID = PB.PersonID
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Base360].[AddressState] S ON rc.state = S.StateCode
LEFT OUTER JOIN Base360.AddressCounty county on rc.county = county.CountyName and s.AddressStateID = county.AddressStateID
INNER JOIN addyCTEInsert2 AB 
         ON ISNULL(rc.addr1,'')  = ISNULL(AB.Address1 ,'')
                    AND isnull(rc.addr2,'') = isnull(AB.Address2,'') 
                    AND isnull(S.AddressStateID,'') = ISNULL(AB.AddressStateID,'')
                    AND isnull(rc.city,'') = isnull(AB.City,'')
                    AND isnull(SUBSTRING(rc.[zip], 1, 5),'') = isnull(SUBSTRING(AB.ZipCode,1,5),'')
                    AND isnull(county.AddressCountyID,'') = ISNULL(AB.AddressCountyID,'')
                    and ab.rownum = 1
INNER JOIN (SELECT x.value('cono[1]','varchar(4)') as cono, x.value('resno[1]','INT') as resno  FROM @Payload.nodes('/Inserted/Row') AS T(x)) as cr 
    on cr.cono = rc.cono and cr.resno = rc.resno
LEFT OUTER JOIN Base360.PersonAddress pa with(nolock) on PB.PersonID = pa.personid and pa.AddressTypeID = -2 and pa.EndDate is null and AB.AddressID = pa.AddressID
WHERE pa.PersonAddressID IS NULL AND (rc.[name_first] IS NOT NULL OR rc.[name_last] IS NOT NULL)
END
```

Comment: Seems like there's a trigger involved?

Comment: I think the error is pretty self explanatory.  Your error says error in SP, and looks like you are missing some code from your SP because the value in the error is not in your code above, please post entire code of SP.

Comment: Post the DDL of the table `ri_res`, **including** any triggers, foreign keys, etc. If any of triggers reference any other objects (like a stored procedure called `SYNC_ri_res_to_WC_PersonAddress`), make sure you include the DDL of those too.

Comment: Your code has no `line 24`.  It has no procedure `SYNC_ri_res_to_WC_PersonAddress`.  And there is no value like `'1094_2'` in your code.  This error message makes no sense, give the code you have provided.

Comment: Those NOLOCKs are likely going to haunt you at some point. You are going to end up with occasional duplicate and/or missing data. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: As for the question at hand, can you provide the xml parameter value being passed in? We might be able to figure out the issue from that but this code is not the easiest to read and has many red flags throughout.

Comment: Not sure what all those random characters had to do with anything in your question, so i removed them. As for your question, what does the SP have to do with your `UPDATE` statement?

Comment: @Larnu It is called by the trigger(s?) that execute due to the update statement.

Comment: What we're all guessing @SMor , but the OP hasn't given us the DDL for said trigger, so we have no idea what it actually being done; we can only guess.

Comment: I suggest you post your procedure (and your code generally) to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Your organization is in need of some serious efforts to improve the code itself and to make it more readable (and therefore understandable). I see scattering of nolock hints without reason, addresses that are composed of empty strings, incomplete addresses, inconsistent use of column refs w/ and w/o aliases, hard-coded special ID values, use of TOP without order, normalization problems (PersonIdentificationValue), etc.